# G-abelian systems

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, ergodic-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $(\mathfrak{A},\alpha,\phi)$ be a $C^*$-dynamical system made of a unital $C^*$-algebra, a $*$-automorphism and an extremal invariant (i.e. ergodic) state.

Consider the covariant GNS representation $(H_\phi,\pi_\phi, V_{\phi,\alpha},\xi_\phi)$, together with the selfadjoint projection $E_{\phi,\alpha}$ onto the invariant vectors of $H_\phi$ under the unitary $V_{\phi,\alpha}$.

Are there concrete examples for which ${\rm dim}(E_{\phi,\alpha}H_\phi)>1$?

Comment: Doesn't the fact that $\dim(E[H]) \geq 2$ contradict the ergodicity of $\phi$? It does in the commutative case.

Comment: No Adrian, ergodicity means extremality among invariant states. ${\rm dim}(E[H])=1$ implies ergodicity, but the converse is true under the additional assumption of $G$-abelianess (in our situation $Z$-abelianess), see Prop. 3.1.12 in Sakai's book. The question is that, at my best knowledge, conterexamples don't exist in literature

Comment: In commutative case, it does hold true: ${\rm dim}(E[H])=1\iff \phi$ is ergodic. Maybe, it is true also if the support of $\phi$ in the bidual is central.

Comment: What is the relation of the title to your question?  I.e., would an example of the sort you want be called a G-abelian (or is it $G$-abelian?) system?

Comment: The relation is explained in one of the comments above.